# Obtaining C varargs with variable size using char[]

Tags: c, variadic-functions, c11

I am writing a container library in `C`, and I would like to use varargs in my implementation, like so:

```
void stack_push(stack *self, T item);
T stack_pop(stack *self);
```

Obviously, C does not have generic types, so instead I use `void *` pointers:

```
void stack_push(stack *self, void *item);
void *stack_pop(stack *self);
```

However, I am thinking of passing input using varargs:

```
void stack_push(stack *self, ...);
```

This could work, because item size is determined at container initialization.

My question is: Is it valid `C` to access vararg members using different type with the same size?

```
void stack_push(stack *self, ...)
{
    struct wrapper {
        char item[self->item_size];
    };

    va_list ap;
    struct wrapper item;

    va_start(ap, self);
    item = va_arg(ap, struct wrapper);
    va_end(ap);

    stack_grow(self, self->size+1);
    memcpy(self->items+self->item_size*self->size++, &item, self->item_size);
}
```

Comment: So how do you intend to identify the type of the objects? Not clear what you ask, but the approach looks fishy.

Comment: You can always use `char`-arrays to carry around anything.

Comment: @akl But does it work with `varargs.h`?

Comment: @akl And is it standard compliant?

Comment: @Olaf For my containers, the type of the objects does not matter, only their size. C is not very type safe anyway, so my containers allow storing e.g. a `unsigned int` in a stack of `int`s, because they are the same size.

Comment: Carrying around data like so is compliant. But do not try to access these `char`-arrays via pointers typed other then `char*`.

Comment: @Olaf Maybe you are confused by the mistake in my example? Anyway, it was supposed to be `memcpy(self->items+self->item_size*self->size++, item, self->item_size);`.

Comment: This `item = va_arg(ap, char[self->item_size]);` won't compile. You cannot assign an array.

Comment: @alk Sorry, I've updated the example code to use a wrapper struct instead. This is valid acording to IBM: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rtref/vaarg.htm
Not sure if the C standard allows it, though.

Comment: I'd say you need to pack the wrapper-struct, as it could get padded and by this be larger than intended.

Comment: From the according man-page: "*... if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), random errors will occur.*"

Comment: Try passing a floating point argument and it will come out as garbage.

Comment: Cannot see how you want to detect the end of the argument list.

Comment: @tofro A correct caller should always pass one argument to `stack_push`, always the size of the item size given on initialization. The point of using varargs is to make the function generic, not to actually use a variable number of arguments.

Comment: Ah, I see. Was somehow assuming you wanted to allow to push more than one item at a time. Your "user" might do so as well...

Comment: Avoiding varargs like the plague is otherwise a sound idea. I see no obvious reason why you need to use them in this program, or indeed in any program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing as you intend provokes undefined behaviour.

From the C-Standard (C11 draft):

> 7.16.1.1 **The va_arg macro**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> 1
>
> ```
> #include <stdarg.h>
> type va_arg(va_list ap, type);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> 2 [...] if
>   *type* is not compatible with the *type* of the actual next argument (as promoted according
>   to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined, except for the following
>   cases:
>
> — one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer
>   type, and the value is representable in both types;
>
> — one type is pointer to void and the other is a pointer to a character type.

None of the two exceptions seem to match your use-case.

Comment: Can you think of a viable solution?

Comment: After doing some testing, I found that `item = va_arg(ap, struct wrapper);` expects _a pointer_ to `struct wrapper`. Can you explain this?

Comment: After doing some _more_ testing, I found that `item = va_arg(ap, struct wrapper);` only expects a pointer when `struct wrapper` contains a variable length array. Weird.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY, what do you mean by variable length array inside a `struct`? This is not allowed (a constraint violation). Do you mean flexible array member?

Comment: @Jens I ment VLA, but the fact that it is not allowed further answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

To further answer my own question: No, it is not possible to obtain varargs as a `char[]` with `sizeof type`:

- `type` in `va_arg(ap, type);` cannot be an array.
- `type` can be a `struct`, but `struct`s cannot have VLAs.
- In the case of GCC, it expects VLA `struct`s to be passed as pointers.
- Multiple calls to `va_arg(ap, char);` result in undefined behaviour. The number of va_arg calls has to equal the number of arguments.

The best you can do is define a type for every possible item size, and use that plus a switch statement instead.

```
struct s1 { char x[1]; };
struct s2 { char x[2]; };
...

void stack_push(stack *s, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    union {
        struct s1 s1;
        struct s2 s2;
        ...
    } u;

    va_start(ap, s);
    switch (s->item_size)
    {
    case 1:
        u.s1 = va_arg(ap, struct s1);
        break;
    case 2:
        u.s2 = va_arg(ap, struct s2);
        break;
    ...
    }
    va_end(s);

    stack_grow(s, self->size+1);
    memcpy(self->items + self->item_size*self->size++, &u, self->item_size);
}
```

However, for anyone trying to implement a similair mechanism (i.e. passing literals instead of pointers), I recommend the following:

```
#include <stack>

#define stack(T) struct {stack actual; T item;}
#define stack_init(s) (stack_init)(&(s)->actual, sizeof((s)->item))
#define stack_push(s, i) ((s)->item = (i); (stack_push)(&(s)->actual, &(s)->item))
#define stack_pop(s) (memset(&(s)->item, 0, sizeof((s)->item)), (stack_pop)(&(s)->actual, &(s)->item), (s)->item)

int main(void)
{
    stack(int) s;

    stack_init(&s);
    stack_push(&s, 3);
    printf("%d\n", stack_pop(&s)); // Prints 3
    printf("%d\n", stack_pop(&s)); // Prints 0
    stack_fini(&s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The disadvantage to this method is that in the case of `stack(stack(int))` it needlessly uses up a lot of `int`s.